# backing up from Ubuntu computer to NAS

Tags: networking, mount, samba, backup, nas

My setup is a Sony Vaio laptop running Ubuntu 13.10 and a BuffaloTech NAS hard-wired to a Netgear 6300 router.

The question is about automating the task of accessing the NAS from the laptop and backing up to it (using rsync).
I wrote a script which mounts the NAS' root "share" folder (i.e. `/share`) to the local mountpoint `..../local_NAS_share`, as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.26/share /media/dan/local_NAS_Share -o username=admin,password=adminpsswrd
```

and this operation works fine.
BTW, I have cifs-utils installed, but NOT Samba.
So the question is this:  if I want to access the NAS via a symbolic link, *not* via a static IP address (as seen above in `//192.168.1.26`), I believe that the BEST way to network the laptop with the NAS is via Samba.  Is that correct?

In other words, if I want to use a line such as
`//BuffaloNAS/share ...` instead of `//192.168.1.26/share`.
I would have to install Samba, which would map the NAS IP address to a symbolic link and resolve it.  Maybe that's not the *only* way of automating the backup task, but I am guessing that it's one of the *better* approaches.  Am I right?

The reason for asking the question in the first place is because the NAS IP is *not* really static; it changes when the NAS is powered down and restarted.  So every time that happens, I have to look up its IP address and change the script, and it would be preferable to automate this task so that the script would not have to be modified.  So I would like to know if Samba is my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve that is to just set a static IP for the NAS. Or you can configure the DHCP-Server so that the NAS always gets the same IP.

After that you can edit the /etc/hosts file and add the NAS (name and IP) so you can use the name BuffaloNAS.